# Javascript: How to access a public variable in the same class?

Tags: javascript, oop, class

I recently started programming JavaScript and thought everything would be good...
Well today I faced a problem I can't solve on my own.
My tutorial/ learning project has a class called model. In this class there are several private and one public variable. This variable is of type CustomEvent:

```
      function Model(){
        /**
         * Array in which the questions are stored
         */
        var questions=new Array();
        var db;
        var valuesSplit="*";
        var tableName="quests";
        this.myEvent=new CustomEvent("my event");
```

So as you can see "myEvent" is public and can be called from outside. In this case it is an event which can be subscribed (this is done outside this class by other objects that want to listen) and it can be fired (this is done in the same class). And this is my problem.
How can I access myEvent within the model class?

I tried:

```
    this.myEvent.fire()
```

and:

```
    myEvent.fire()
```

But I always get "myEvent is not defined".

Comment: where exactly are you writting this.myEvent.fire() or  myEvent.fire()? please share that code, if you are writting it inside a function in the class this.myEvent.fire() should work...

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It tried it directly under the declaration and inside a public function of the class. Nothing worked for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the first thing to say is: JavaScript doesn't have classes. The sooner you stop thinking of "JavaScript classes," the better off you'll be. :-) JavaScript has OOP, but not the kind with classes. Your `Model` function is called a *constructor function*.

You can access `myEvent` from any code that has a reference to the object created by `new Model`, which includes code in your constructor (via `this` — e.g., the way you're setting it up) and any function called with `this` referring to that object (or, of course, "externally" via `someObjReference.myEvent`).

So probably `this.myEvent.fire()` is what you want, but the code you're calling it from doesn't have the right `this` value. That's because in JavaScript, `this` is controlled entirely by *how a function is called*, not *where the function is defined* as it is in some other languages. See my blog articles [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)  and [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html) for more details, but I've done a somewhat truncated discussion below.

Here's an example of a fairly standard way to set up a constructor function with useful methods that all instances share:

```
function Foo() {
    this.myEvent = new CustomEvent("my event");
}
Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    this.myEvent.fire();
};

// Usage:
var f = new Foo();
f.bar();          // Fires the event indirectly, via the code in `bar`
f.myEvent.fire(); // Fires it directly
```

Note that that only works if `bar` is called with `this` referring to an object with a `myEvent` property. It's easy to call `bar` with `this` set to something else entirely:

```
document.getElementById("someID").onclick = f.bar;
```

When the click occurs, the `bar` function gets called, but `this` does **not** refer to an object created via `Model`. (It will refer to the element with the id "someID" instead.) And so this line in `bar`

```
this.myEvent.fire();
```

...will fail.

If you're used to class-based languages, you can see how this is totally different from, say, Java, C#, or C++. In those langauges, `this` inside `bar` will always refer to an object created via `new Model`. Not so JavaScript, which is both awkward and powerful.

This flexibility of functions (not being bound to any particular object) is one of the biggest things to get used to, and take advantage of, in JavaScript. The other is how functions are *closures*, which is powerful but [not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).

So if `this` is set by how a function is called, how do you do that? There are two ways:

1. Call the function by referencing it from an object property in the same expression as the call. That's an awkward way of saying do this:

   ```
   var f = new Foo();
   f.bar();    // <== The key bit
   f["bar"](); // <== Also works
   ```

   The expression `f.bar()` does two things, which interact: The first thing it does is retrieve the property `bar` of the object referenced by `f`, and get that property's value (which is a function reference). Then it *calls* that function (because of the `()`). The way JavaScript works, because you did those two things in the same overall expression, the interpreter sets `this` to `f` during the call to `bar` for you. But note this key distinction:

   ```
   var f = new Foo();
   var b = f.bar;
   b(); // <== Different!
   ```

   Now when the `bar` function gets called, `this` will *not* be set to `f` (it'll be set to the global object, which is `window` on browsers), because we've separated the property retrieval from the function call.
2. Alternately, you can use the built-in features of JavaScript function objects, their `call` and `apply` functions. `call` and `apply` do exactly the same thing, the only difference between them is how you supply the arguments for the function. Example:

   ```
   var f = new Foo();
   f.bar(1, 2):       // <== Calls `bar` with `this` === `f` and passing in
                      //     the arguments 1 and 2
   var b = f.bar;
   b.call(f, 1, 2);   // <== Does the same thing as f.bar(1, 2)
   var args = [1, 2];
   b.apply(f, args);  // <== Does the same thing as f.bar(1, 2)
   ```

   E.g., `call` and `apply` allow you to set what `this` should be *explicitly* when you call the function. The only difference between them is that `call` accepts the arguments to give the function as further arguments to `call`, and `apply` accepts them as an array.

Comment: +1 for saying "The sooner you stop thinking of "JavaScript classes," the better off you'll be. :-) JavaScript has OOP, but not the kind with classes.", the best way to remember this is "think of javascript functions as behaviour which can carry data"......rather than thinking them as classes which have data and behaviour operating on them...

Comment: Wow. That helped. Thank You very much. Javascript is actually a lot lot different than any other language I know so far. In fact i find it really hard to understand all the structures behind it :/

Comment: @user999041: Glad that helped. Yes, if you're used to class-based languages, JavaScript looks similar but functions differently. (And if you're used to prototypical languages, JavaScript looks different but behaves similarly.)

Comment: Yeah, thanks again for that uber-good explanation above. I just did what you showed on your blog: a new variable inside my model (var self=this). Now I can use "self" just as my well-known this. Would you say this is a clean way which i can use all the time?

Comment: @user999041: It depends on what you're doing. If you're creating all of your functions within your constructor function, it's a convenient way to do that, yes. Note, though, that that means each object gets its *own* copy of that function (they can't be shared). The `Foo` example above putting `bar` on the prototype instead allows the `bar` function to be shared by all instances of `Foo` (but means the `self` trick won't work).

Comment: Alright. I saved that thread in my OneNote file :). You helped a ton.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `myEvent` in a non public function in your `Model` than you have to create another reference to the `myEvent` which isn't using the `this` reference of your Model. Because the `this` in another function is something else than in your `Model` function. The easiest way to bypass this problem is if you define a new variable in your `Model`:

```
var that = this;
```

Then you can call your `myEvent` like:

```
that.myEvent
```

Answer (score 0):

The `myEvent` member should be visible both in the inner & outer scope of the object :

```
function Model(){
    this.myEvent = 'some value';
    this.canAccessEvent = function(){
        return 'myEvent' in this;
    }
}

var m = new Model();
// access from outside : 
alert(m.myEvent);
// access from inside : 
alert('Model can access the even? ' + m.canAccessEvent());
```

However, it is very possible that your `new CustomEvent` function doesn't exist or does not return a valid object making your `myEvent` variable to be `undefined`. I suggest you attribute some other value to the `myEvent` property and see if it is defined. If it is defined, then the problem lies in your `CustomEvent` function.